# Getting "Using where; Using index" in Extra column of EXPLAIN when only querying indexed fields

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

When running the following query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    belgarath.match_oc_history.id_, belgarath.match_oc_history.tour_id
FROM
    belgarath.match_oc_history
        JOIN
    belgarath.tournament_oc ON belgarath.tournament_oc.tour_id = belgarath.match_oc_history.tour_id
        AND belgarath.tournament_oc.orig_id = belgarath.match_oc_history.tournament_oc_orig_id;
```

I get the following table:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type |      table       | partitions | type  |                                                                                          possible_keys                                                                                           |                         key                          | key_len |                               ref                               | rows  | filtered |          Extra           |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tournament_oc    | NULL       | index | uq__tournament_oc__tour_id__orig_id,ix__tournament_oc__tour_id,ix__tournament_oc__orig_id                                                                                                        | uq__tournament_oc__tour_id__orig_id                  |       6 | NULL                                                            | 26550 |      100 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | match_oc_history | NULL       | ref   | ix__match_oc_history__five_keys,ix__match_oc_history__tour_id,fk__match_oc_history__player_oc_p1_idx,fk__match_oc_history__player_oc_p2_idx,fk__match_oc_history__tour_id__tournament_oc_orig_id | fk__match_oc_history__tour_id__tournament_oc_orig_id |       5 | belgarath.tournament_oc.tour_id,belgarath.tournament_oc.orig_id |    54 |      100 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
```

My understanding from reading around is that if a query is only working with indexed fields then it shouldn't need to use `where`. Is this correct?

If yes, then why am I seeing it pop up in the `EXPLAIN` table?

If no, should I be concerned about the use of `where` in this instance? I've always assumed that `where` is slower than `index`...

Table compositions:

```
CREATE TABLE `tournament_oc` (
  `updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tour_id` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `orig_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uq__tournament_oc__tour_id__orig_id` (`tour_id`,`orig_id`),
  KEY `ix__tournament_oc__tour_id` (`tour_id`),
  KEY `ix__tournament_oc__orig_id` (`orig_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__tournament_oc__tour_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tour_id`) REFERENCES `tour` (`id_`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27788 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci


CREATE TABLE `match_oc_history` (
  `updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tour_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `tournament_oc_orig_id` int NOT NULL,
  `round_oc_id` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `player_oc_orig_id_p1` int NOT NULL,
  `player_oc_orig_id_p2` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_`),
  KEY `ix__match_oc_history__five_keys` (`tour_id`,`tournament_oc_orig_id`,`round_oc_id`,`player_oc_orig_id_p1`,`player_oc_orig_id_p2`),
  KEY `ix__match_oc_history__round_oc_id` (`round_oc_id`),
  KEY `ix__match_oc_history__tour_id` (`tour_id`),
  KEY `fk__match_oc_history__player_oc_p1_idx` (`tour_id`,`player_oc_orig_id_p1`),
  KEY `fk__match_oc_history__player_oc_p2_idx` (`tour_id`,`player_oc_orig_id_p2`),
  KEY `fk__match_oc_history__tour_id__tournament_oc_orig_id` (`tour_id`,`tournament_oc_orig_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__match_oc_history__player_oc_p1` FOREIGN KEY (`tour_id`, `player_oc_orig_id_p1`) REFERENCES `player_oc` (`tour_id`, `orig_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__match_oc_history__player_oc_p2` FOREIGN KEY (`tour_id`, `player_oc_orig_id_p2`) REFERENCES `player_oc` (`tour_id`, `orig_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__match_oc_history__round_oc_id` FOREIGN KEY (`round_oc_id`) REFERENCES `round_oc` (`id_`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__match_oc_history__tour_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tour_id`) REFERENCES `tour` (`id_`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__match_oc_history__tournament_oc` FOREIGN KEY (`tour_id`, `tournament_oc_orig_id`) REFERENCES `tournament_oc` (`tour_id`, `orig_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1516084 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

---

**As per comments:**

`SHOW WARNINGS` statement response:

```
/* select#1 */ select `belgarath`.`match_oc_history`.`id_` AS `id_`,`belgarath`.`match_oc_history`.`tour_id` AS `tour_id` from `belgarath`.`match_oc_history` join `belgarath`.`tournament_oc` where ((`belgarath`.`match_oc_history`.`tournament_oc_orig_id` = `belgarath`.`tournament_oc`.`orig_id`) and (`belgarath`.`match_oc_history`.`tour_id` = `belgarath`.`tournament_oc`.`tour_id`))
```

Comment: Your table order in EXPLAIN is in oposite direction than in join. Maybe there is additional where on tournament_oc ? 

IN my explain there is proper table order and 'using index' in both lines in 'Extra' column

Comment: You could use STRAIGHT_JOIN (instead of JOIN) to force proper join order in your query.

Comment: Hi Grzegorz. Thanks for the comments. When you say "Your table order in EXPLAIN is in oposite direction than in join" - what would cause this? I'm also not sure what you mean by an "additional where on tournament_oc" - I've posted everything I have? Also - when you say "IN my explain" do you mean you've taken my table definitions and re-created the query or it's a general approach you follow?

Comment: I recreated structure and run explain on select. In my example both rows contains "using index". Maybe order is not meaningfull.. but still looks like different execution plan

Comment: Use a STRAIGHT_JOIN (instead of JOIN) in query and run EXPLAIN again

Comment: `STRAIGHT_JOIN` worked! Any guesses on what might be going on?

Comment: try MYSQL Workbench or command line to gather more information

[MYSQL Extended explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-extended.html)

Comment: Added this to the post - doesn't look like there's much there? Appreciate you sticking with me btw...

Comment: Why include `tournament_oc` if you don't fetch any of the columns from it?

Comment: @GrzegorzKraska - I don't see any advantage in forcing the order of the tables via `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.  What is your argument for it?

Comment: @RickJames Just curiosity. As you described engine is free to build execution plan, and is almost always right. But still we have, in corner cases, a lot of ways to adjust or overwrite optimizer decisions through [Optimizer Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-overview), which is of course totally not recommended, but it's sometimes life saver.

Comment: @GrzegorzKraska - Yes.  I see the "hints" as serving two purposes:  (1) an emergency fix when a regression slips in; (2) the rare case where the data is so skewed that the Optimizer makes the wrong estimate.  In this Question, I don't understand why the Join order might get the wrong results.  I'm even skeptical about whether the Join order would matter much for performance.  Was the result wrong?  Or slower?

Comment: The straight join resulted in only an index being used for the MRE I'd used. However, when I built it into the larger 'real life' query it seemed to enforce straight joins for all my other joins which slowed the whole thing down A LOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Using index` means that the entire query (at least for the table in question) does not need any columns other that what is in the `INDEX`.  This is faster than having to bounce between the Index's BTree and the data's BTree.
- The Optimizer is free to reorder `JOINed` tables as it sees fit.  The `EXPLAIN` reflects what the Optimizer decided.
- The "warning" shows how it decided to execute the query.
- `OR` is often turned into `WHERE` when parsing.  (You were correct to use `ON`, since that is how the tables are related.)
- Without a true `WHERE`, the Optimizer [usually] picks the smaller table, then does a "nested loop join" (NLJ) to reach into the next table.  And this is often the faster way to perform the query.  I see no need for `STRAIGHT_JOIN`; trust the Optimizer.
- You have optimal composite indexes to let the Optimizer pick either table first, optimally.
- Why do you think that the 'wrong' table went first?
- "Using where" does not mean much; ignore it.
- "where is slower than index" -- This does not make sense.  A `WHERE` clause *with* a suitable index will make the query run faster.  An `ON` clause almost always needs an index to run faster.  (What you have is effectively `ON`.)